# How to serialize DRF ManyToManyField "through" model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I cannot make DRF serialize intermediate "through" model properly. Here's an example code.

Models

```py
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track, through='AlbumTrack')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class AlbumTrack(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'track')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.album.title} - {self.track.title} ({self.score})"
```

Serializers

```py
class AlbumTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    track_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='track.pk')
    track_title = serializers.CharField(source='track.title')
    track_score = serializers.CharField(source='score')

    class Meta:
        model = AlbumTrack
        fields = ('track_id', 'track_title', 'track_score')


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = AlbumTrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('title', 'tracks')
```

When I access /api/albums/ I get an exception:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `id` on serializer `AlbumTrackSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Track` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Track' object has no attribute 'track'.
```

DRF appears to be resolving `tracks` to a `Track` QuerySet before serializing it. Is it possible to prevent that? I need to serialize `AlbumTrack` model in order to access `score` field.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from a colleague. I had to add `source='albumtrack_set'` to a serializer field. So, here's a working version of the serializer.

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = AlbumTrackSerializer(many=True, source='albumtrack_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('title', 'tracks')
```